# Is there a way that dynamic Link can carry values or intents can be included in them

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

So I'm using kotlin to build an app of places and I have implemented a share button using dynamic links to share each place and when clicked, the app will open to that specific place, skipping the splash activity. It was working fine before but I modify my code to use one activity for opening all this different places using intent.putExtra(), and retrieving it with getStringExtra(). So now the dynamic links are opening a blank activity because the information is only retrieve with getStringExtra() and the dynamic links do not carry those values. Is there a way to implement those values to tthe dynamic links? I have tried many ways and I don't seem to find the solution.

```
       <activity
        android:name=".food.Category"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <!--Drinks-CoffeeShops-->
            <data android:host="myapp.page.link" android:scheme="https" android:path="/Drinks/CoffeeShops/1/"  />
            <data android:host="myapp.page.link" android:scheme="https" android:path="/Drinks/CoffeeShops/2/" />
            ...
            <!--Food-FastFood-->
            <data android:host="myapp.page.link" android:scheme="https" android:path="/Food/FastFood/1/" />
            <data android:host="myapp.page.link" android:scheme="https" android:path="/Food/FastFood/2/" />
            ...
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is my android manifest and the dynamic links are sharing exactly how they are intended to be.

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    checkForDynamicLinks()
}

private fun checkForDynamicLinks() {
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(intent).addOnSuccessListener {

        Log.i("Share", "We have a dynamic link!")
        var deepLink: Uri? = null

        if (it != null) {
            deepLink = it.link
        }
        if (deepLink != null) {
            Log.i("Share" , "Here's the deep link Url:\n" +
                    deepLink.toString())
        }


    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Log.i("Share", "Oops, we couldn't retrieve dynamic link data")
    }
}

private fun generateSharingLink(
    deepLink: Uri ,
    getShareableLink: (String) -> Unit = {} ,
) {
    val dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink().run {
        link = deepLink

        domainUriPrefix = "https://myapp.page.link/"

        androidParameters {
            build()
        }


        buildDynamicLink()
    }

    getShareableLink.invoke(dynamicLink.uri.toString())
 }
     override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

   //Drinks-CoffeeShops
    val coffeeShops = intent?.getStringExtra("DrinksCoffeeShops").toString()
    //Food-FastFood
    val foodFastFood = intent?.getStringExtra("FoodFastFood").toString()
    
   if (id == R.id.shareButton){

        generateSharingLink(

            deepLink =

            when {
                //Drinks-CoffeeShops
                coffeeShops.toIntOrNull() in (1..50) -> {
                    "https://myapp.page.link/Drinks/CoffeeShops/$coffeeShops/".toUri()

                }
                //Food-FastFood
                fastFood.toIntOrNull() in (1..50) -> {
                    "https://myapp.page.link/Food/FastFood/$fastFood/".toUri() }

                else -> { "https://myapp.page.link/".toUri() }
            }




        ) { generatedLink ->
            // Use this generated Link to share via Intent
            shareDeepLink(generatedLink)
  }
 }
  }

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
  
   private fun shareDeepLink(deepLink: String) {

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

    intent.type = "text/plain"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT , "Share")
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , deepLink)

    val app = intent.resolveActivity(packageManager)
    val unsupportedAction = ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.fallback/.Fallback")
    if (app != null && app != unsupportedAction) try {
       
        val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent , "Share Using:")
        startActivity(chooser)
        return
    } catch (ignored: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    }
    Toast.makeText(this , "Required App not Installed" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figure a way to assign an intent to the incoming dynamic link and if someone is also looking for a similar solution I will share what I did.
So I had to retrieve the parameters of the link by using:

```
val deepLink = if (Firebase.dynamicLinks.getDynamicLink(intent).isSuccessful){
        Firebase.dynamicLinks.getDynamicLink(intent).result.link
    }else{
        Log.e("TAG", "No incoming link")
    }
```

Notice that I used `if() else()` statement, that's because If I didn't the activity will always expect a link to open, and if I tried to normally use the app without a link, it was going to crash.

After retrieving the dynamic link I have to know which link was clicked to give each one of them values. This is an example of my link:
`https://myapp.page.link/Category/1/` or `https://myapp.page.link/SubCategory/1/`

So to make the specific link do something I simply made an expression like:

```
if("Category" in deepLink){
//do something
}
if("SubCategory" in deepLink){
//do something
}
```

Hope this helps!